# Recover a Class File was never Saved in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

How to recover a  class file which was executed and not saved in vb 6.0?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As you said, it was never saved. Sorry :(

Comment: Depends on what "a class file" means I guess.

Answer (score 5):

If you click on `Tools -> Options...` and select the `Environment` tab, you will find a little box headed "When Program Starts". If you select "Prompt to save changes", the IDE will ask whether you want to save the changes you have made before running the program.

A crash during execution need not then result in the loss of your changes.

It's too late to save what you have just lost, but it might prevent it happening again.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean that you opened the VB IDE, wrote some code in a class file, ran the code, and then crashed or closed the IDE without saving the class file, then it's too bad: you have lost the code.